# NGINX proxy_pass and upstream SSL certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, proxy, certificate

community!

I have a reverse proxy based on NGINX.
The idea is to provide my customers with custom domains for my services.
For example, the customer will create a CNAME record pointing to my Proxy server:
video.mycustomer.com --> mynginxserver.com

Then I generate the SSL certificate (Let'sEncrypt) and create the following Virtual host:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name video.mycustomer.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/$server_name-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/$server_name-error.log;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri; # Redirect to https
        }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name video.mycustomer.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/$server_name-ssl-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/$server_name-ssl-error.log;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/video.mycustomer.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/video.mycustomer.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

        location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            root /web/sites/$server_name/www/;
        }
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://myservice.com/channel/cfa-xw88bbxlsd/; 
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
    }
```

As long as I'm pointing to an **HTTP** everything works like a charm.
But when I try to set the proxy_pass to an HTTPS resource (my resource and I owe the certificate), I'm getting **502 Bad Gateway**.

This is what I get from the error.log file:

```
==> video.mycustomer.com-ssl-error.log <==
2021/10/19 18:56:44 [error] 11316#11316: *1333 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 86.79.99.252, server: video.mycustomer.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://98.64.64.90:443/", host: "video.mycustomer.com"
2021/10/19 18:56:44 [error] 11316#11316: *1333 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 86.79.99.252, server: video.mycustomer.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://98.64.64.79:443/", host: "video.mycustomer.com"
2021/10/19 18:56:44 [error] 11316#11316: *1333 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 86.79.99.252, server: video.mycustomer.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://98.64.64.24:443/", host: "video.mycustomer.com"
2021/10/19 18:56:44 [error] 11316#11316: *1333 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 86.79.99.252, server: video.mycustomer.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://98.64.64.4:443/", host: "video.mycustomer.com"
2021/10/19 18:56:44 [error] 11316#11316: *1333 connect() to [2600:8000:2153:2000:d:1f52:c300:83b1]:443 failed (101: Network is unreachable) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.79.99.252, server: video.mycustomer.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://[2600:8000:2153:2000:d:1f52:c300:83b1]:443/", host: "video.mycustomer.com"
2021/10/19 18:56:44 [error] 11316#11316: *1333 connect() to [2600:8000:2153:1200:d:1f52:c300:83b1]:443 failed (101: Network is unreachable) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.79.99.252, server: video.mycustomer.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://[2600:8000:2153:1200:d:1f52:c300:83b1]:443/", host: "video.mycustomer.com"
2021/10/19 18:56:44 [error] 11316#11316: *1333 connect() to [2600:8000:2153:c200:d:1f52:c300:83b1]:443 failed (101: Network is unreachable) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.79.99.252, server: video.mycustomer.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://[2600:8000:2153:c200:d:1f52:c300:83b1]:443/", host: "video.mycustomer.com"
2021/10/19 18:56:44 [error] 11316#11316: *1333 connect() to [2600:8000:2153:b200:d:1f52:c300:83b1]:443 failed (101: Network is unreachable) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.79.99.252, server: video.mycustomer.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://[2600:8000:2153:b200:d:1f52:c300:83b1]:443/", host: "video.mycustomer.com"
2021/10/19 18:56:44 [error] 11316#11316: *1333 connect() to [2600:8000:2153:b000:d:1f52:c300:83b1]:443 failed (101: Network is unreachable) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.79.99.252, server: video.mycustomer.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://[2600:8000:2153:b000:d:1f52:c300:83b1]:443/", host: "video.mycustomer.com"
2021/10/19 18:56:44 [error] 11316#11316: *1333 connect() to [2600:8000:2153:5200:d:1f52:c300:83b1]:443 failed (101: Network is unreachable) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.79.99.252, server: video.mycustomer.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://[2600:8000:2153:5200:d:1f52:c300:83b1]:443/", host: "video.mycustomer.com"
2021/10/19 18:56:44 [error] 11316#11316: *1333 connect() to [2600:8000:2153:4a00:d:1f52:c300:83b1]:443 failed (101: Network is unreachable) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.79.99.252, server: video.mycustomer.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://[2600:8000:2153:4a00:d:1f52:c300:83b1]:443/", host: "video.mycustomer.com"
2021/10/19 18:56:44 [error] 11316#11316: *1333 connect() to [2600:8000:2153:2600:d:1f52:c300:83b1]:443 failed (101: Network is unreachable) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.79.99.252, server: video.mycustomer.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://[2600:8000:2153:2600:d:1f52:c300:83b1]:443/", host: "video.mycustomer.com"
```

I tried to work with:

```
proxy_ssl_certificate     /home/ubuntu/ssl-proxy/pass_cert/client.pem;
proxy_ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/ssl-proxy/pass_cert/client.key;
```

With no luck.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance,
Dan.

Answer (score 2):

This config solved all the issues:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name video.mycustomer.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/video.mycustomer.com-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/video.mycustomer.com-error.log;
        return 301 https://video.mycustomer.com$request_uri; # Redirect to https
        }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name video.mycustomer.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/video.mycustomer.com-ssl-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/video.mycustomer.com-ssl-error.log;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/video.mycustomer.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/video.mycustomer.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

        location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            root /web/sites/video.mycustomer.com/www/;
        }
        location / {
            proxy_pass https://myservice.com/channel/cfa-xw88bbxlsd/; #HTTP not HTTPS + add "/" suffix
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
            proxy_ssl_server_name on;
            proxy_read_timeout 5m;
            proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
            proxy_set_header Content-Encoding gzip;


        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have to say that I'm completely baffled _why_ your solution works, and what was the 'magic' command that made it working! The good news — for me at least — is that it _does_ work exactly as you say! I wonder if you could share some insights on those extra parameters that your're sending upstream, and why you chose to pick them. Thanks!

Comment: For me, it was the two lines of `proxy_ssl_*` under the location block. Thanks!

Comment: Ditto... adding `proxy_ssl_*` under the location block worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My 502 SSL handshake error was simply due to

```
proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:1234/;
```

When the application was actually listening on

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1234/;
```